# vue.js: exclude core-js from webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, core-js

Here is my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      "vue": "Vue",
      "core-js": "core-js",
    },
  },
};
```

With this config, vue.js (Vue) library is excluded and I can link it from a CDN.

But **core-js** is packed anyway and not recognized as an external library.

What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change babel config.

Here is my `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset",
      {
        useBuiltIns: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Found this a while ago. Forgot to post it here. Thanks mate.

Comment: Hi, I'm using vue-cli4, it give an error: ```[BABEL] /Users/rolin/workspace/github/financial_tools_app/src/main.js: Unknown option: .useBuiltIns. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
- Maybe you meant to use
"preset": [
  ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset", {
  "useBuiltIns": false
}]
]```
But the babel formatter always trim quotes, do you know how to fix this error ?